# How to partition a List by a property of each element

Tags: scala, partitioning

I have a question about partitioning a list by a property of each list element.

Given a `List[E]` and a function `f(e: E): Int` how can the list be partitioned into a `List[List[E]]` where each element is a `List[E]` of elements that have the same value when `f` is applied?

For example suppose type `E` represents a physical displacement and `f` measures the displacement resulting in an integer which is greater than or equal to zero.

```
val ms = List(a, b, c, d, e)

f(a) = 1
f(b) = 3
f(c) = 1
f(d) = 4
f(e) = 3
```

The resulting partition would be

```
List(List(a, c), List(b, e), List(d))
```

This example shows that the values of `f` can include gaps but the list of lists should not contain any empty lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the list to be sorted by the function values:

```
list.groupBy(f).toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just group them:

```
val ms = List(a, b, c, d, e)
ms.groupBy(x => f(x)).values
```

Comment: Or even more idiomatic: `ms.groupBy(f).values`

Comment: to make it an actual List one would have to add a .toList